# Setting Drupal Image Field via Services, and image won't attach to node?

Tags: 7, services

I'm uploading an image via my iOS app and setting a created node's image field to the image through Drupal Services. Everything appears to be correct (see uploaded photo from 'Recent Logs'). However when I navigate to the node, the image field is empty? Any idea as to why this might be? All help is appreciated, thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party, but I think you might be encoding the image wrongly. You need base64 encoding. Here is how encoding works on my end with Python 3.5.2:

```
import os, base64
size = os.path.getsize(filename)
filesize = os.stat(filename).st_size
filemime = mimetypes.guess_type(filename)
fd = open(filename, 'rb')
image_data = base64.b64encode(fd.read())
fd.close()
```

Comment: Why do you say that?  The `file` element in the picture seems to be base64, and attempting to decode the beginning of the visible fragment reveals a JFIF header which looks correct to my (untrained) eye.